# adhesive for metal to glass

Tags: adhesive

I have a metal hallow medallion that I want to glue to glass. I have tries gorilla glue, silicone adhesive, e-6000, jewelry and metal glue from Aileens. Because of the hallow center nothing adheres. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Autozone and purchase automotive weatherstripping adhesive from 3M (8008). That stuff is seriously sticky and long lasting. It will take a few hours to set up, though. I have a test plate of glass that I've glued all sorts of things and have left outside in the elements for the last 5 years and still cannot pry anything off without breaking the glass.